# Geometric function operations are slow on Redshift

Tags: performance, geometry, amazon-redshift

I'm having general performance issues when I use the st_intersects function on geometries on Redshift. This operation is really slow and I'm trying to find a way to speed up the process.

The following query is really slow:

```
    select *
    from public.A a
    join public.B b on st_intersects(b.geom, a.centroid);
```

The query is a lot faster by first calculating a bounding box around the geometry and pre-filtering on the latitude/longitude within the bounding box. Afterwards applying the st_intersects function to be sure that the point lays within the polygon.

```
    select *
    from public.A a
    join public.B b on a.lon >= min_lon and a.lon <= max_lon 
           and a.lat >=min_lat and a.lat <= max_lat 
           and st_intersects(b.geom, a.centroid);
```

How should I improve the performance of geometry function queries without using these kind of hacks?